# How to store intermediary result in conditional of SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
    select id, (sum(col2) - sum(col1)) as net_col1_col2
    from data4sim
    where end_time <= :input_time
    and (sum(col2) + sum(col1)) > 0
    and (
      (sum(col1) + sum(col2))
      <= abs(coalesce(col3, 0) - (col4 - (sum(col2) - sum(col1)))) + :EPS
    )
    group by id
```

This is my first time using SQL, and I'm trying to write a query that conditions on the above. I noticed that I am computing `(sum(col1) + sum(col2))` and also `(sum(col2) - sum(col1))` twice, and I'm not sure how to store the intermediate result so I can reuse it in the second one.

Can I do something like this:

```
where time < :input_time
  and (sum(col1) + sum(col2)) as temp
  and (temp > 0)
  and (temp < col3) <= ....
```

I think in general, I don't know how to store intermediary results in the conditional.

Comment: You're not necesarily 'computing' things twice, database engines are extremely smart and may (or may not) optimize this away. You can check the query execution plan to see more information on what the engine does.

Comment: Indeed, depending on your specific platform (you haven't said and no answer is possible without it) the optimizer is very probably only defining and computing the expression once - the concept of intermediary results or code re-use is more relevant to imperative programming; read up on the declarative nature of sql.

Comment: If you could please share what RDBMS you are using. Some SQL dialects allow aliases to be defined in the SELECT clause which can then be reused elsewhere. That being said, as others here have pointed out, it's likely superfluous syntax anyway as SQL is a declarative language and the sql engine will decide how it actually gets executed through a series of optimization steps it takes prior to execution. You mostly just worry about describing what results you want using SQL and let the RDBMS take care of the rest.

Comment: @JNevill I am using sqlite3

Comment: BTW you seem to mix columns and aggegation in a `where` clause. Looks like MySQL. Only this DB engine allows such bad things. And of course sqlite

Comment: @juergend sorry, I don't understand. What is the issue with that?

Comment: Please share your complete statement. It needs adjustment

Comment: Sum() groups together more than one record. Don't mix that with single column conditions. `group by` handles group data

Comment: Probably you need to define and work with a derived table - a SQL fragment though is not useful to work with.

Comment: @juergend I just updated the OP with the complete query (note that I haven't tested this so I don't know if it works)

Comment: It's a bit of a complicated statement, so even if I'm not actually "storing a temporary result," I think it'd simplify things and make it clearer if I added an alias, e.g., I want to give a name (such as `derived_col`) to `(col4 - (sum(col2) - sum(col1))`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know you data but something like this should do it:

```
select id, 
       (sum(col2) - sum(col1)) as net_col1_col2,
       (sum(col2) + sum(col1)) as total
from data4sim
where end_time <= :input_tum    
group by id
having total > 0
   and total <= abs(coalesce(col3, 0) - (col4 - net_col1_col2)) + :EPS
```

You can uses aliases from the `select` in the `having` clause.

Comment: "I don't know you data" -- is this answer depdent on the data type? I believe all the cols used in this query are floats

Comment: Also, in the `select` statement, it also selects `total`, but I don't actually need `total`. So will this result require me to filter out `total` (note I am using this in a python environment)

Comment: I added a sum() here and there asuming what you want to do. But I know know the logic behind it

Comment: ah, the `sum(coalesce(col3, 0))` shouldn't be necessary, it should just be `coalesce(col3, 0)). ditto with `sum(col4)`. also in `and net_col1_col2 <= ` it should be `and total <= `

Comment: This approach returns 3 entries (id, net_col1_col2, total) per row, right? Is it possible to not return `total` but keep it as an alias

Comment: No, either select `total` or you cannot use the alias. But as someone else mentioned - the optimizer will probably cache the sum calculation. The alias is just for better readability.

Answer (score 1):

In sqlite you can alias a column in your SELECT clause and then refer to that alias in your HAVING clause (which is where you should move your conditions that are build on aggregates like `SUM()`).

```
CREATE TABLE test (id integer, val1 integer, val2 integer);
INSERT INTO test (id, val1, val2) VALUES (1,1,5);
INSERT INTO test (id, val1, val2) VALUES (2,3,6);
INSERT INTO test (id, val1, val2) VALUES (3,5,7);

SELECT SUM(val1 + val2) as derived_col
FROM test
WHERE id IN (1,2)
HAVING derived_col > 3;
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/OFA_qqJZ)